How do dynamically start a webserver based on an .env variable?
I want Playwright to start a web server when the environment is set to local. However, for a reason that I fail to understand, it doesn't work when trying to use an environment variable from a .env.test with dot config. It ONLY works when I set the environment via shell command, such as export ENVIRONMENT='LOCAL' yarn playwright test.
This is an example of the playwright.config I am using.
import { defineConfig, devices } from '@playwright/test';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { defineBddConfig } from 'playwright-bdd';

import { E2E_BASE_URL, E2E_SERVER_PORT } from './constants';

dotenv.config({ path: '.env.test' });

const testDir = defineBddConfig({
  features: '*.feature',
  steps: ['*.ts'],
  outputDir: '.temp/specs',
  quotes: 'single',
});

export default defineConfig({
  timeout: 30_000,
  testDir,
  outputDir: '.temp/results',
  snapshotPathTemplate: 'snapshots/{testName}/{platform}-{projectName}/{arg}.{ext}',
  reporter: [['html', { outputFolder: '.temp/report' }]],
  use: {
    baseURL: E2E_BASE_URL,
    screenshot: 'only-on-failure',
    video: 'retain-on-failure',
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    trace: 'on-first-retry',
    testIdAttribute: 'data-tracking-id',
  },
  webServer:
    process.env.ENVIRONMENT === 'LOCAL'
      ? {
          command: `yarn codegen && next dev -p ${E2E_SERVER_PORT}`,
          url: E2E_BASE_URL,
          reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
        }
      : undefined,

  fullyParallel: true,
  forbidOnly: Boolean(process.env.CI),
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : 5,

  projects: [
    {
      name: 'Chrome',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] },
      fullyParallel: true,
      testMatch: '*.feature.spec.js',
    },    
  ],
});

For additional context, the value of the E2E_BASE_URL in the constants.ts depends on which environment is set in the .env.test file and works just fine, meaning the file is being read correctly. The issue happens ONLY when starting the test process. I would appreciate any feedback and explanation on why this is happening. I know I can create scripts with the pre-defined variable in it, but I would prefer to have it working just based on the .env.test file if that can be done.

Code looks OK to me--can you share a sample .env.test, relevant package.json and the commands you're running? Possibly also a tiny sample test file, so it's a complete example that I can easily run to reproduce the issue? Thanks.

Do any values that you set in your .env.test get picked up by the config? Your dotenv may not be configured correctly (pointing at the wrong file?). What's the location of .env.test relative to your config file?

@agoff, both the playwright.config and the .env.test are at the root of the web app. I don't have other variables from the .env loaded there, but I will try to move the .env.test somewhere else, load it, and check if it will work.

@ggorlen As soon as I have some free time, I will try to create a sample project and share it here!
